# How do I use HTML code while working within <script> cast in an HTML File?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create some **HTML** code to randomly select questions out of a question bank, and display them when called. In this sample code I'm testing with a bank of 4 and to select 4 questions. However, when I run it, nothing happens.

I've cast `<html>` over the html parts and they work fine outside the `<script>` parts, but not inside. Below is the code that I have so far for the proof of concept for this idea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<script> 
boolean is0 = false;
boolean is1 = false;
boolean is2 = false;
boolean is3 = false;

while(i <= 4) {
    int thisNumber = (int) (Math.random()*4)

    if(thisNumber == 0 && is0 == false) {
    <html>  <form name="theForm">

        <b> Question 1: </b>
        <p> Which of the following smartphone features controls screen orientation <br>
        Select the button that best answers the question. </p>

        <form action="Results.pdf" method="get">
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="gyro"> Gyroscope<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="nfc"> NFC<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="accel"> Accelerometer<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="gps"> GPS
        </form>
    </html>
    is0 = true;
    i++;
    }

    if(thisNumber == 1 && is1 == false) {
    <html>  <form name="theForm">

        <b> Question 1: </b>
        <p> Which of the following smartphone features controls screen orientation <br>
        Select the button that best answers the question. </p>

        <form action="Results.pdf" method="get">
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="gyro"> Gyroscope<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="nfc"> NFC<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="accel"> Accelerometer<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="gps"> GPS
        </form>
    </html>
    is1 = true;
    i++;
    }

    if(thisNumber == 2 && is2 == false) {
    <html>  <form name="theForm">

        <b> Question 1: </b>
        <p> Which of the following smartphone features controls screen orientation <br>
        Select the button that best answers the question. </p>

        <form action="Results.pdf" method="get">
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="gyro"> Gyroscope<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="nfc"> NFC<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="accel"> Accelerometer<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="gps"> GPS
        </form>
    </html>
    is2 = true;
    i++;
    }

    if(thisNumber == 3 && is3 == false) {
    <html>  <form name="theForm">

        <b> Question 1: </b>
        <p> Which of the following smartphone features controls screen orientation <br>
        Select the button that best answers the question. </p>

        <form action="Results.pdf" method="get">
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="gyro"> Gyroscope<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="nfc"> NFC<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="accel"> Accelerometer<br>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="gps"> GPS
        </form>
    </html>
    is3 = true;
    i++;
    }
</script>



</body>
```

I'm wondering if I'm not calling it right or how I would get it to display a form type if it's "question number" is selected. I'm trying to get the question and radio buttons to display when the question number is called.

Comment: There's so much wrong with your JS code I don't even know where to start. Either way, if you like generating HTML with a scripting language as in the code provided, you might want to look at PHP instead of JavaScript. PHP is much more suitable for this way of generating HTML than JavaScript.

Comment: Your whole approach is flawed. 
Questions should be defined in a JavaScript model, not in html. Then use ANY (literally : ANY) front-end frameworks (Knockoutjs, react (Actually no, not this one), vue.js, angular, doesn’t matter). These frameworks will help you to build a corresponding html

Comment: The code you have provided is not valid JavaScript and there is no actual HTML. You appear to be mixing script and HTML which doesn't work. What you propose is possible but you probably need to get something basic working first, there should be plenty of JavaScript tutorials to help. Unfortunately your question doesn't have a specific enough problem which SO can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there are quite a few things that need changing in order to for this code to begin to work:

**First: remove the html from inside the script tag.** The only thing that belongs in the script tag is Javascript. HTML is not Javascript, and so all of that should be taken out and placed in the appropriate place in the body tag (outside of `<script>`). If you do see code examples that appear to have HTML embedded in Javascript as you do, it is probably JSX, which can't be run by vanilla Javascript anyway.

**Next, make sure what you are writing is valid Javascript.** As far as I know, what you have currently isn't valid. Javascript is a dynamically typed language, and so the only way to declare variables is with `const` and `let` (ES6), or `var`. Feel free to look for a few tutorials and learn more about Javascript, how to write it, and how to interact with the DOM.

Comment: I'm trying to write the file to be opened as a local HTML file on the machine. The HTML ran fine by itself. I've never actually messed with JavaScript, and the code is a variation of something I wrote myself for a Java program except it just printed out text in the console. The `i` incrementing is correct because I only want `i` increasing if one of the `if` statements are met, and if none are met, then it starts over with a new random number and tries the conditions again. Is there a way to add questions selected to a temporary list to then be written to the screen with HTML?

Comment: With each iteration, you can update the HTML accordingly by appending a string that includes your HTML to the previous node. Or save the data for each iteration in an array and then create all the HTML at once.